# Numpy change diagonal values in a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, diagonal

I have a vector with the following values: `dv = array([0., 0., 1.])`.

How do I diagonalize this vector into a 3D array with each element in the vector have its own diagonal:

```
array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]]])
```

So far i have tried:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((3,3,3))
di = np.diag_indices(3,3)
a[di] = dv
```

This is almost correct, but it does not change all of the elements on the diagonal.

Comment: What are you trying to do with teh diagonal?

Comment: Are you trying to set a fixed set of values for each sub matrix in the diagonal?

Comment: Yes, i want each element in the vector dv mapped to its own diagonal in each sub matrix.

Comment: The sub matrix being the last two dimensions in a = np.zeros((3,3,3))

Comment: So, 1 in the third matrix repeats in the diagonal as values?

Comment: Index `a` with 2 or more `np.arange(3)`.  Your choice of axis.  Use `:` for the other, if any.

Comment: Yes, for example dv = [1,2,3] i want [1,1,1] in the diagonal for the first sub matrix, [2,2,2] in the diagonal for the second sub matrix and [3,3,3] in the diagonal for the third sub matrix.

Comment: Look at `di`.  Does that give you any ideas?

Comment: Not sure, `di` has values `[0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2]` which are the correct indices in each sub matrix i think.

Comment: For the diagonals of the sub matrices, you basically need `:, [0,1,2], [0,1,2]` instead of `[0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2]`. Because right now, you are only using the 3D diagonal of a cube that you have made. Check my approach to see if that works for you.

Comment: Ok, that is correct. I don't want to index the first dimension. Thank you.

Comment: Second thing is to repeat the values. Since you have a 1D array, the values will get mapped to each diagonal as `[0,0,1]`. What you can do is to reshape it to `[[0],[0],[1]]` so that each value is repeated while assignment thanks to broadcasting. So each diagonal has repeated values set from `dv`

Comment: For anyone reading this, i found that einsum supports writeable returned arrays (since version 1.10.0). So this is an alternative solution: 

`np.einsum('...ii->...i', a)[:] = dv[...,None]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
a = np.zeros((3,3,3))
dv = np.array([0, 0, 1])

i,j = np.diag_indices(3) #diagonal indices for a 2D matrix (3,3)
a[:,i,j] = dv[:,None]
a
```

```
array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]]])
```

You basically get 2D matrix diagonals and use those to get a view of the 3 diagonals from the original matrix. You then repeat the diagonal values you want to update to the same shape by broadcasting and map it to the diagonals.

---

**The above approach is based on fetching a view from the original numpy array and then using assignment to update it**. If you are not trying to do an assignment task, you can simply use `arr.diagonal` with `axis1` and `axis2` parameters to get a copy of the diagonal values for those 2 axes. Note, the shape of those axes must be equal (square matrix)

```
a = np.arange(0,2*3*3).reshape(2,3,3)

# array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
#         [ 3,  4,  5],
#         [ 6,  7,  8]],

#        [[ 9, 10, 11],
#         [12, 13, 14],
#         [15, 16, 17]]])

a.diagonal(axis1=1, axis2=2)

# array([[ 0,  4,  8],
#        [ 9, 13, 17]])
```